# Monopoly Die Rolling Expected Value

Tags: expectation, conditional-expectation

In the board game Monopoly, players roll two fair six-sided dice on each of their turns. The sum of the two dice determines how many spaces the player moves his or her game piece on the board. If the two dice roll the same number, this is called “doubles.” Whenever a player rolls doubles, that player rolls again and moves his or her game piece again. However, if a player rolls doubles three times on his or her turn, the player moves directly to "jail" (which we will considered a total move of 0 -- ignoring all previous moves).

What is the expected value of the number of spaces a player moves his or her game piece during that player’s turn?

The solution does this by conditioning on the double rolls; it made sense but my answer is very slightly off and i'm wondering why. Label $E$ as the expected value. Label $E_d$ as the expected value of a double roll. Label $E_{dd}$ as the expected value of two double rolls. $E_{ddd}$ is simply zero. I created the following system of linear equations.

(1) $ E =\frac{5}{6}(7) + \frac{1}{6}(E_{d})$
(2) $E_{d} = \frac{5}{6}(7+7) +  \frac{1}{6}(E_{dd})$
(3) $E_{dd} = \frac{5}{6}(7 + E_{d}) + \frac{1}{6}(0)$

Solving i'm off by 0.01. What's the problem?

Comment: Not sure I understand your third equation.  Conditioned on throwing doubles twice, I expect to get $21$ fives sixths of the time and $0$ the remaining sixth.  That gives me $E=\frac {595}{72}\approx 8.2639$.  Your system  gives me $\frac {770}{93}\approx 8.2796$.

Comment: I made the equation by saying 5/6 of the time the two double roll will add 7 to the expected value of the one double roll, and 1/6 of the time, itll result in zero. What's the logical flaw in that? And yes, that was the correct answer.

Comment: I don't see where $E_d$ comes into play in the third equation. You already promised me I threw two doubles, the only mystery is the third throw.

Comment: Having thrown two doubles I expect to have moved $14$ spaces.  Now on my next roll I either give it all up (prob $\frac 16$) or I expect to add another $7$.  Thus $E_{dd}=\frac 56\times 21 +\frac 16\times 0$.

Comment: yeah that makes sense.